# Problema ao realizar login com Grails 3 no Kubernetes

Tags: spring-security, grails, escalabilidade

Estou com problemas na autenticação do meu sistema. Estou utilizando **Grails 3 com SpringSecurity** e quando vou escalar para 2 ou mais réplicas no meu cluster Kubernetes a autenticação para de funcionar.

O que eu pude notar é que a requisição está me retornando um **Status Code: 302** após realizar a autenticação, mas não consigo saber o motivo do problema.

Obs: Tenho uma outra aplicação rest **Grails 3 usando SpringSecurity com autenticação JWT** que funciona corretamente ao escalar a aplicação para mais de 1 réplica, imagino que porque toda requisição preciso passar o **Authorization Token** e não é mantido uma sessão da aplicação.